# How to run a Java Main method of a Class during Eclipse Start up in the background ?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a option in eclipse that I can add start up hook, so at the start of eclipse it can execute a main method class of my java project ? Is this doable ? or Do I require to make a eclipse plugin ?

Comment: If you want to run code as part of Eclipse you must write an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way of doing it is to create a plugin with an Extension for org.eclipse.ui.startup ([org.eclipse.ui.startup documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html%22)). You will have to provide a class that implements the interface org.eclipse.ui.IStartup. It's in that class where you should call the main method of your class.

Another option is to create an OSGi Bundle, install that bundle in Eclipse and configure it to start automatically, then you can provide an Activator for it that runs the task you want in the start(BundleContext) method.

In either case, your class/es must be part of the plugin's classpath or packaged as a plugin/OSGi bundle marked as a dependency of the startup bundle.

Now, may I ask what do you want to achieve?